# How to programmatically get SVN revision description and author in c#?

Tags: c#, svn

How do I programmatically get the revision description and author from the SVN server in c#?

Comment: Do you actually want to query an SVN server or just get the revision number/description for the latest SVN commit in your project directory?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.net/):

```
using(SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> list;

    // When not using cached credentials
    // c.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass")l

    SvnLogArgs la = new SvnLogArgs { Start = 128, End = 132 };
    client.GetLog(new Uri("http://my/repository"), la, out list);

    foreach(SvnLogEventArgs a in list)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("=== r{0} : {1} ====", a.Revision, a.Author);
       Console.WriteLine(a.LogMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and how to get numer of last revision?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to find a C# SVN API to use. A quick Google search found [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/).

To get message and author for specific revision

```
SvnClient client = new SvnClient();
SvnUriTarget uri = new SvnUriTarget("url", REV_NUM);

string message, author;
client.GetRevisionProperty(uri, "svn:log", out message);
client.GetRevisionProperty(uri, "svn:author", out author);
```

Comment: I know there are some libraries with SVN in its name, but what I would like to know how to do this from someone who did it before.

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar to this a while back, we needed notification of certain repository commits.

I ended up using [SubversionNotify](http://www.subversionnotify.com/) to do this.  You could take a look at the code there and see what you can use.

I do believe SubversionNotify is grabbing output from svnlook.  Svnlook has quite a few arguments that can get what you're looking for.

If you know the revision number and repository:

```
svnlook info -r [rev#] /path/to/repo
```

Will net you the User, Timestamp, Log message length, and the log message itself:

```
bob
2009-03-25 11:10:49 -0600 (Wed, 25 Mar 2009)
19
Did stuff with things.
```