# Setuptools: find SVN revision from a parent directory

Tags: python, svn, setuptools

In the Python package I'm putting together I'm using the following `setup.cfg` file:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build = dev
tag_date = 1
tag_svn_revision = 1
```

However when I run `python setup.py sdist` the SVN revision appears as `-r0`. This is likely because there is no `.svn` directory where I run the setup script; in fact my tree is

```
 main_dir/
   .svn/
   branches/
   trunk/
     setup.py
     setup.cfg
```

How can I tell `setuptools` to go find the SVN revision number in a parent directory? I still want to keep using my package **version** number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the `-r0` problem in a different way if you're willing to install another package.  Setuptools does not support the SVN metadata since version 10. The functionality has been moved to the [setuptools_svn](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools_svn) package.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. That should be somewhere in the documentation! Cheers

Comment: There's an entry in the [10.0 changelog](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/history.html#id85). It's probably not obvious though what the consequences of the change are.

Comment: Thanks @RjOllos for the solution! I removed the `tag_svn_revision` from my setup.cfg file, so now the -r0 does not get appended to my version, however, now it always appends a 0 to my post release tag. My version becomes `zuko-0.1dev0-py2.7.egg`. I don't want the 0 appended after dev. Any idea why this is happening? I am using setuptools version 28.8.0.

Comment: I don't know that it's possible to have `dev` rather than `dev0`, but the reason for appending the `0` is described in [PEP-440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#implicit-development-release-number).

Answer (score 1):

My solution at the moment is to combine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501219/204634) and build the version manually like this (minus the `shell=True` option):

```
# Hat tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501219/204634
import subprocess

def svnversion():
    p = subprocess.Popen("svnversion", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
    return stdout

_version = '{}-{}'.format(my_pkg_version, svnversion())
```

Whilst the `setup.cfg` file contains:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build = dev
tag_date = 1
```